# y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape () instead

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I have a trained and saved a model. I am trying to further train the model on new data but it gives error.
Relevant part of the code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
# The maximum number of words to be used. (most frequent)
MAX_NB_WORDS = 50000
# Max number of words in each complaint.
MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 250
# This is fixed.
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_NB_WORDS, filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~', lower=True)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(master_df['Observation'].values)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv=CountVectorizer(max_df=1.0,min_df=1, stop_words=stop_words, max_features=10000, ngram_range=(1,3))
X=cv.fit_transform(X)

with open("../sgd.pickle", 'rb') as f:
    sgd = pickle.load(f)

def output_sample(sentence):
    test=preprocess_text(sentence)
    test=test.lower()
    #print(test)
    test=[test] 
    tokenizer.fit_on_sequences(test)
    new_words= tokenizer.word_index
    #print(word_index)``
    test1=cv.transform(test)
    #print(test1)
    output=sgd.predict(test1)
    return output[0]

def retrain(X,y):
    X=preprocess_text(X)
    X=X.lower()
    X=[X]
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)
    new_words=tokenizer.word_index
    X=cv.fit_transform(X)
    sgd.fit(X,y)
    with open('sgd.pickle', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(sgd, f)
    print("Model trained on new data")

sentence=input("\n\nEnter your observation:\n\n")
output=output_sample(sentence)
print("\n\nThe risk prediction is",preprocess_text(output),"\n\n")

print("Is the above prediction correct?\n")
corr=input("Press 'y' for yes or 'n' for no.\n")

if corr=='y':
    newy=np.array(output)
    retrain(sentence,newy)

elif corr=='n':

    print("What is the correct risk?\n1. Low\n2. Medium\n")
    r=input("Enter the appropriate number: ")

    if r=='1':
        newy=np.array('Low')
        retrain(sentence,newy)
    elif r=='2':
        newy=np.array('Medium')
        retrain(sentence,newy)
    else:
        print("Incorrect input. Please restart the application.")

else:
    print("Incorrect input. Please restart the application")
```

When the program is run the error occurs at `sgd.fit(X,y)`. The error is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11300/3528077041.py in <module>
      5     newy=[output]
      6     print(newy)
----> 7     retrain(sentence,newy)
      8 
      9 elif corr=='n':

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11300/2433836763.py in retrain(X, y)
      7     X=cv.fit_transform(X)
      8     #y = y.reshape((-1, 1))
----> 9     sgd.fit(X,y)
     10     with open('sgd.pickle', 'wb') as f:
     11         pickle.dump(sgd, f)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    344             if self._final_estimator != 'passthrough':
    345                 fit_params_last_step = fit_params_steps[self.steps[-1][0]]
--> 346                 self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
    347 
    348         return self

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_stochastic_gradient.py in fit(self, X, y, coef_init, intercept_init, sample_weight)
    727             Returns an instance of self.
    728         """
--> 729         return self._fit(X, y, alpha=self.alpha, C=1.0,
    730                          loss=self.loss, learning_rate=self.learning_rate,
    731                          coef_init=coef_init, intercept_init=intercept_init,

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_stochastic_gradient.py in _fit(self, X, y, alpha, C, loss, learning_rate, coef_init, intercept_init, sample_weight)
    567         self.t_ = 1.0
    568 
--> 569         self._partial_fit(X, y, alpha, C, loss, learning_rate, self.max_iter,
    570                           classes, sample_weight, coef_init, intercept_init)
    571 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_stochastic_gradient.py in _partial_fit(self, X, y, alpha, C, loss, learning_rate, max_iter, classes, sample_weight, coef_init, intercept_init)
    529                              max_iter=max_iter)
    530         else:
--> 531             raise ValueError(
    532                 "The number of classes has to be greater than one;"
    533                 " got %d class" % n_classes)

ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1 class
```

The data sample is as follows:

```
Observation                                             Risk
0   A separate road for light vehicle should be ma...   Low
2   All benches were not having sufficient berm.        Low
3   As light arrangement is not adequate.               Low
4   As light arrangement is not adequate.               Low
5   As contractor's equipment record is not availa...   Low
77  First aid Room is not established.                  Medium
98  Heavy dust on haul road is found with in suffi...   Medium
79  First aid station is maintained in the Rest sh...   Medium
171 Presently explosive van is not available with ...   Medium
79  First aid station is maintained in the Rest sh...   Medium
```

It should ideally take the input but I don't know why its giving that error.

Comment: Add `y = y.reshape((-1, 1))` before calling fit method.

Comment: @meti I tried this and now it gives this error `The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1 class`.

Comment: The error message indicates `y` vector contains only one label type! please add your data if it is possible ;) @Chinmay Datar

Comment: @meti Added data sample in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up the code and made several changes to `retrain` function, Now the function would add a new *String and Label* to the trainset and fit the classifier again. Other parts of your code stay the same logically!

Utility functions:

```
def output_sample(sentence):
    test=preprocess_text(sentence)
    test=test.lower()
    test=[test] 
    tokenizer.fit_on_sequences(test)
    new_words= tokenizer.word_index
    test1=cv.transform(test)
    output=sgd.predict(test1)
    return output[0]

def preprocess_text(string):
    # do whatever you want but return String afterward ;)
    return string

def retrain(X,y):
    X=preprocess_text(X)
    X=X.lower()
    X=[X]
    X = cv.fit_transform(master_df['Observation']+X)
    new_words=tokenizer.word_index
    sgd.fit(X,master_df['Risk']+y)
    with open('sgd.pickle', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(sgd, f)
    print("Model trained on new data")
```

Actual Flow:

```
import numpy as np 
import pickle
import nltk
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
cv=CountVectorizer(max_df=1.0,min_df=1, stop_words=stopwords, max_features=10000, ngram_range=(1,3))
master_df = pd.read_csv('classification.tsv')
X=cv.fit_transform(master_df['Observation'])
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

try:
    f = open("./sgd.pickle", 'rb')
    sgd = pickle.load(f)
except:
    sgd = SGDClassifier()

sgd.fit(X, master_df['Risk'].to_list())


sentence=input("\n\nEnter your observation:\n\n")
output=output_sample(sentence)
print("\n\nThe risk prediction is",preprocess_text(output),"\n\n")

print("Is the above prediction correct?\n")
corr=input("Press 'y' for yes or 'n' for no.\n")

if corr=='y':
    newy=np.array(output)
    retrain(sentence, newy)

elif corr=='n':

    print("What is the correct risk?\n1. Low\n2. Medium\n")
    r=input("Enter the appropriate number: ")

    if r=='1':
        newy=np.array('Low')
        retrain(sentence,newy)
    elif r=='2':
        newy=np.array('Medium')
        retrain(sentence,newy)
    else:
        print("Incorrect input. Please restart the application.")

else:
    print("Incorrect input. Please restart the application")
```

Comment: Thank you soo much mate. It works. Just curious when we call ```.fit``` does it train the model from scratch or just further trains the model based on new input?